# Problems with connecting to database using PDO class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So here is the deal. I wanted to create login screen for my web application but it seems that I stuck at accessing table (korisnici) in my database.

I keep getting this line of text when I try to login:

***Fatal error:*** Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'

Here is my code:

```
<?php
 session_start();

// sadrži podatke potrebne za spajanje na bazu
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); // naziv servera - najčešće nije potrebno mijenjati ako je server lokalni
define('DB_NAME', 'razvrstane_ceste'); // naziv baze
define('DB_USER', 'razvrstane'); // korisnik za spajanje
define('DB_PASS', 'razvrstane'); // lozinka baze


 //PDO Database Connection
 try {
 $databaseConnection = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS );
 $databaseConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 } catch(PDOException $e) {
 echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
 }


//PDO Database Connection


 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $errMsg = '';
 //ime and password sent from Form
 $ime = trim($_POST['ime']);
 $lozinka = trim($_POST['lozinka']);

 if($ime == '')
 $errMsg .= 'You must enter your Username<br>';

 if($lozinka == '')
 $errMsg .= 'You must enter your Password<br>';


 if($errMsg == ''){
 $records = $databaseConnection->prepare('SELECT id,ime,lozinka FROM  korisnici WHERE lozinka = :lozinka');
 $records->bindParam(':ime', $ime);
 $records->execute();
 $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 if(count($results) > 0 && password_verify($lozinka, $results['lozinka'])){
 $_SESSION['ime'] = $results['ime'];
 header('location:razvrstane_ceste.php');
 exit;
 }else{
 $errMsg .= 'Username and Password are not found<br>';
 }
 }
 }

?>


<html>
<head><title>Login Page PHP Script</title></head>
<body>
 <div align="center">
 <div style="width:300px; border: solid 1px #006D9C; " align="left">
 <?php
 if(isset($errMsg)){
 echo '<div style="color:#FF0000;text-align:center;font-size:12px;">'.$errMsg.'</div>';
 }
 ?>
 <div style="background-color:#006D9C; color:#FFFFFF; padding:3px;"><b>Login</b></div>
 <div style="margin:30px">
 <form action="" method="post">
 <label>Korisnik  :</label><input type="text" name="ime" class="box"/><br /><br />
 <label>Zaporka  :</label><input type="password" name="lozinka" class="box" /><br/><br />
 <input type="submit" name='submit' value="Submit" class='submit'/><br />
 </form>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `bind_param` is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line of code:

```
$records = $databaseConnection->prepare('SELECT id,ime,lozinka FROM  korisnici WHERE lozinka = :lozinka');
 $records->bindParam(':ime', $ime);
```

here you are in the WHERE condition the parameter name is :lozinka and in bindParam() method you have the parameter name as :ime, make the parameter names same at both placese

use the below code:

```
$records = $databaseConnection->prepare('SELECT id,ime,lozinka FROM  korisnici WHERE lozinka = :lozinka');
 $records->bindParam(':lozinka', $ime);
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thx for the fast solution. Indeed it fixed  previous PDO error (**PDOException**) so thank you all for fast and correct respond (+1).  But now it raised new issue. Now it seems that I have issue with username and password. I get error message `$errMsg .= 'Username and Password are not found<br>'`;

Comment: it returns variable  `$errMsg` with value of _Username and Password are not found_

Comment: $errMsg is not your PDO error but your data missing in your database error message. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Hmmm, there seems to be problem with database for sure. Nevertheless, thank you all for quick response.

Answer (score 1):

You have put in the incorrect name for the parameter when you are using `:lozinka`

`$records->bindParam(':ime', $ime);`

needs to be

`$records->bindParam(':lozinka', $ime);`

Or change the parameter in the prepare statement.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you provided wrong placeholder and binding value with other,

```
 if($errMsg == ''){
 $records = $databaseConnection->prepare('SELECT id,ime,lozinka FROM  korisnici WHERE lozinka = :lozinka');
 $records->bindParam(':ime', $ime);

it should be like:
 if($errMsg == ''){
 $records = $databaseConnection->prepare('SELECT id,ime,lozinka FROM  korisnici WHERE lozinka = :lozinka');
 $records->bindParam(':lozinka', $ime);
```

Bind lonzinka